# Prevent docker-compose from reinstalling requirements.txt while using a built image

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have an app ABC, which I want to put on docker environment. I built a Dockerfile and got the image abcd1234 which I used in docker-compose.yml 
But on trying to build the docker-compose, All the requirements.txt files are getting reinstalled. Can it not use the already existing image and prevent time from reinstalling it?

I'm new to docker and trying to understand all the parameters. Also, is the 'context' correct? in docker-compose.yml or it should contain path inside the Image?

PS, my docker-compose.yml is not in same directory of project because I'll be using multiple images to expose more ports.

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: /Users/user/Desktop/ABC/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    image: abcd1234
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
      - PROJECT_ENV=development
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim-buster AS build
MAINTAINER ABC

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN python3 -m venv /venv
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y git && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential && \
    apt-get install -y awscli && \
    apt-get install -y unzip && \
    apt-get install -y nano

RUN apt-get install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev

COPY . /ABC/

RUN apt-cache search mysql-server
RUN apt-cache search libmysqlclient-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql
RUN apt-cache search postgresql-server-dev-9.5


RUN pip install --upgrade awscli==1.14.5 s3cmd==2.0.1 python-magic
RUN pip install -r /ABC/requirements.txt

WORKDIR .
```

Please guide me on how to tackle these 2 scenarios. Thanks!

Comment: How do you start your services? If you're doing `docker-compose up` images won't be rebuilt unless you specify `--build` flag.

Comment: You can also optimize your Dockerfile. You can put your `COPY . /ABC/` at the bottom and before installing dependencies you only copy `requirements.txt`. That way your dependencies won't be reinstalled on every build unless you actually added some dependency (Docker can reuse layers from cache). So when you change something in code only that layer (and the ones below/after) will be rebuild.

Comment: Thanks @StefanGolubović the build of dockerfile was successful in first attempt, I want to avoid re-installations of requirements.txt while taking build of docker-compose. Will try out this way too. PS. I'll just make the containers up and hit the APIs of Django app at port 8000 (via postman), and will integrate multiple apps inside docker-compose., each app at different port.

Comment: How it is supposed to work without installing requirements.txt ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `context:` directory is the directory on your host system that includes the `Dockerfile`.  It's the same directory you would pass to `docker build`, and it frequently is just the current directory `.`.

Within the Dockerfile, Docker can *cache* individual build steps so that it doesn't repeat them, but only until it reaches the point where something has changed.  That "something" can be a changed `RUN` line, but at the point of your `COPY`, if any file at all changes in your local source tree that also invalidates the cache for everything after it.

For this reason, a typical Dockerfile has a couple of "phases"; you can repeat this pattern in other languages too.  You can restructure your Dockerfile in this order:

```sh
# 1. Base information; this almost never changes
FROM python:3.6-slim-buster AS build
MAINTAINER ABC
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /ABC

# 2. Install OS packages.  Doesn't depend on your source tree.
# Frequently just one RUN line (but could be more if you need
# packages that aren't in the default OS package repository).
RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get upgrade -y && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
      build-essential unzip libxrender-dev libpq-dev

# 3. Copy _only_ the file that declares language-level dependencies.
# Repeat starting from here only if this file changes.
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# 4. Copy the rest of the application in.  In a compiled language
# (Javascript/Webpack, Typescript, Java, Go, ...) build it.
COPY . .

# 5. Explain how to run the application.
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python manage.py migrate && \
    python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: thanks alot.. that helped. PS, got to know 1 thing,... no need to build dockerfile if we're using docker-compose... coz eventually we'll build docker-compose first before running. was making mistakes in grasping the concepts.. but eventually got it.